# Unity TileMap has no tiles

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have created a tilemap containing several tiles using the Tile Palette Gamobject brush in Unity. The tilemap is correctly rendered when I run my game.

[TileMap created](https://i.stack.imgur.com/epfIr.png)

However when I try to access the tiles from code no tiles can be accessed. I used the following script

```
Tilemap tileMap = GetComponent<Tilemap>();
    List<Vector3> availablePlaces = new List<Vector3>();
    Debug.Log(tileMap.name+" Tiles are " + tileMap.size.x+", "+ tileMap.size.y + ", "+ tileMap.size.z);
    Debug.Log("Cell bounds: " + tileMap.cellBounds.x + ", " + tileMap.cellBounds.y + ", " + tileMap.cellBounds.z);
    for (int n = tileMap.cellBounds.xMin; n < tileMap.cellBounds.xMax; n++)
    {
        for (int p = tileMap.cellBounds.yMin; p < tileMap.cellBounds.yMax; p++)
        {
            Vector3Int localPlace = (new Vector3Int(n, p, (int)tileMap.transform.position.y));
            Vector3 place = tileMap.CellToWorld(localPlace);
            if (tileMap.HasTile(localPlace))
            {
                //Tile at "place"
                availablePlaces.Add(place);
            }
            else
            {
                //No tile at "place"
            }
        }
    }
```

The values x, y, z of tileMap.size are 0,0,1
The values x, y, z of tileMap.cellBounds are 0,0,0

Does anyone know what am I doing wrong? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

When you use the GameObject brush no tiles are instantiated. Instead, this brush what does is to instantiate a new clone of that GameObject aligned to the Grid of the Tilemap.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but I just had the same issue.  T
he work around I am using for now is to not use the GameObject brush and instead create the levels programmatically. For example to create a simple rectangle you could so something like this:

```
 // draw initial walls
        Vector3Int borderOrigin = new Vector3Int(0, 0, 0);
       
 
        for(int h = 0; h <= height; h++)
        {
            for (int w = 0; w <= width; w++)
            {
             
                Vector3Int newPos = borderOrigin + new Vector3Int(w, h, 0);
             
                if(h == 0 | w == 0 | h == height | w == width)
                {
                    Debug.Log(newPos.ToString());
                    Tile wallTile1 = ScriptableObject.CreateInstance<Tile>();
                    wallTile1.gameObject = wallPrefabBorder;
                 
                    myTileMap.SetTile(newPos, wallTile1);
                }
            }
 
        }
```

I'm sure there are much more efficient means of plotting out a rectangle, but since I only need to do it once this sloppiness worked.